# Only return part of a class value

Tags: javascript, partial

I need to return only a portion of a classes value. I can not for the life of me figure out how to display everything before the "-" and then a separate return of after the "-"
I have

```
 function() {
var productprice = document.getElementsByClassName("dynamic_qty")[0].value; 
    return productprice;
    }
```

and it returns this as an example '$69.61–$213.33' 
How do I return just the 69.91? ANd separately how do I return just the 213.33?
I know I can strip the $ signs out with

```
return productprice.replace("$", "");
```

but how do I get the numbers before or after the "-" ? Thanks

Html

```
 <div class='price'>
    <input type="text" class="dynamic_qty" id="price_18" value="$69.61&ndash;$213.33" readonly="readonly" onfocus="this.blur()" />

</div>
```

Comment: can you add the html?

Comment: `value.split("-").map(n => n.substr(1))`

Comment: `const [from, to] = '$69.61–$213.33'.match(/\d+\.\d+/g)`

Comment: @le_m i would add a positive lookbehind and add that as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `split()` to split the value into an array and then return the first element.

```
var productprice = document.getElementsByClassName("dynamic_qty")[0].value.split('-')[0];
```

To get the part after `-` use `[1]` instead of `[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions will be your friend here, you can read up on them [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

To answer your question though, you can use "/(\d*.\d*)/" as the matching pattern

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best answer comes as a combination of 2 of the comments on your answer:

```js
let [from,to] = 
    '$69.61–$213.33'     //input string
    .split("–")          //split the string on the dash
    .map(p=>p.substr(1)) //remove the first character from each value
    
console.log(from,to)
```